# Como não fazer acesso indevido com ponteiros?

Tags: c++, ponteiro

Tenho um código onde crio e depois leio um arquivo `.dat` com informações de registros de venda, como data, hora, preço, etc. Eu consigo fazer uma pesquisa por data, por exemplo, e gerar outro arquivo `.dat` só com os registros de compra daquela data, porém, quando uso a função de leitura para ler esse novo arquivo gerado ela não consegue acessar as informações que estão no registro, o programa capota, como se fosse algum acesso indevido do ponteiro, ao meu ver.

header.h

```
class RegistroVenda{    // classe com os dados que vou salvar no arquivo
public:
    string data, hora, cidade, etc.... ;
};
```

file.cpp

```
RegistroVenda * v = new RegistroVenda(); // uso v para acessar a classe, deixo aqui em cima pra ficar global

void Leitura(string nome_arquivo){ // na primeira chamada da função tudo vai funcionar
    
    fstream arquivo(nome_arquivo, ios::in|ios::binary); ... ok

    //verifico se abriu certo... ok
    //calculo tamanho do arquivo... ok

    for(int i=0; i<tamanho_arquivo; i++){

        /* .read() ta lendo um bloco de dados e passando pra v, que é global,
           então ele deveria acessar os atributos da classe corretamente */

        arquivo.read( (char*)v, sizeof(RegistroVenda) ); 

        cout << "cidade = " << v->cidade << endl; // só que quando tento acessar a cidade por exemplo, da erro
    }
}
```

Na primeira vez que rodo o programa ele vai ler um arquivo `.txt`, vai salvar os dados num arquivo `.dat`, depois eu consigo pesquisar nesse arquivo `.dat` e o resultado da pesquisa eu salvo em outro arquivo `.dat`. Até aqui tudo funciona beleza.

Depois vou chamar a mesma função que leu antes (e deu certo) para ler o resultado da pesquisa, só que é aí que o programa capota. Quando chegar a hora de acessar os atributos ( `v->cidade` por exemplo) ele capota.

Por que `v` não consegue acessar o conteúdo das variáveis na segunda vez que eu rodo a função? Parece que, ao rodar uma segunda vez, ele perde a referência de alguma coisa e acaba fazendo um acesso indevido.

Comment: Poste um programa inteiro, compilável. Poste um exemplo do arquivo txt para ter um mínimo reproduzível do problema por quem queira ajudar. Não use variáveis globais. Nunca. Use uma classe Venda e as operações de que precisa. Trabalhe com as vendas na memória se possível, usando algum dos vários containers que a linguagem oferece. E grave apenas ao final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema estava girando em torno das variáveis do tipo `String`. A solução que encontrei foi a seguinte:

1º) Mudar o tipo das variáveis da estrutura

```
class RegistroVenda
{
public:
    float preco;
    char nome[30]; // troca string por isso
};
```

2º) Fazer uma cópia do tipo `string` pro tipo `char[]` usando `strcpy()` e `c_str()`

```
char linha[TAM_LINHA];
string s;

while(!arquivo.eof()){
        RegistroVenda r;
        arquivo.getline(linha,TAM_LINHA);
        r.preco = atof(strtok(linha,";")); // atof() convert pra float

        s = strtok(NULL,";");    
        strcpy(r.nome,s.c_str()); // copia string de 's' e passa pra 'nome'
}
```

Então seguinte, `strtok()` vai ler uma sequência de caracteres na minha `linha` até o delimitador `;`, que eu uso pra separar os dados do registro. O segundo dado do meu registro é o `nome`, porém não posso passar `linha` como parâmetro novamente, se não ele vai voltar do começo da linha, e isso não é o que quero. Eu quero continuar na mesma linha, então passo `NULL` como parâmetro e digo qual é o próximo delimitador.

Beleza, agora faço `s` receber uma string de caracteres, continuando na mesma linha que li e está guardada em `linha`. Essa string é o nome, e então faço uma cópia de `s` para `nome`.

Pronto, feito isso o arquivo `.bin` gerado com os registros poderá ser lido normalmente em execuções distintas. Não consigo explicar por que variáveis do tipo `string` deram errado e do tipo `char[]` deram certo. Se alguém puder explicar melhor sobre isso, fico grato.

Comment: Obs: vetor de char é bem sensível, no sentido de que da bastante problema ao usar. Fui usar ele num outro exercício e só de alterar o tamanho do vetor char ele gerava respostas diferentes. Se tiverem problema com uma variável `char vet[xx]`, testem alterar o tamanho do vetor.